# Python date comparison not giving correct result, am I missing something super simple?

Tags: python, sorting, date, datetime

As part of a larger project I need to check if due dates have passed to mark tasks overdue, I'm relatively new at this so I could 100% be overlooking something glaringly obvious, but my date comparison isn't outputting the correct result. what am I missing?

Thank you in advance! :)

so this is my test attempt..

```
import datetime

date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("25.12.2022", '%d.%m.%Y').strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime("25.12.2025", '%d.%m.%Y').strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
today = datetime.date.today().strftime('%d.%m.%Y')

if date1 < today:
    print("OVERDUE")
else: 
    print("not overdue")
    
if date2 < today:
    print("OVERDUE")
else:
    print("not overdue")
```

I intentionally set `date1` to be overdue just to make sure it worked but despite that I still get the 'not overdue' option for both `date1` and `date2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that, because you called `strftime` on your datetime and date objets, `date1`, `date2` and `today` aren't date objects, they're strings. So, the string "25.12.2022" is not less than "06.01.2023" (ie. `date1 < today` is False). The obvious solution here is to remove the call to `strftime` but then you'll have the issue of comparing dates and datetimes. To fix that, you can do either of the following:

### As Dates

Convert all your objects to dates, and compare them that way. This just means calling `date()` on `date1` and `date2`, like so:

```
import datetime

date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("25.12.2022", '%d.%m.%Y').date()
date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime("25.12.2025", '%d.%m.%Y').date()
today = datetime.date.today()
```

### As Datetimes

Convert all your objects to datetimes. This just means replacing your call to `today` with a call to `now`, like so:

```
import datetime

date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("25.12.2022", '%d.%m.%Y')
date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime("25.12.2025", '%d.%m.%Y')
today = datetime.date.now()
```

In either case, the comparison will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You should compare in the format **[%Y%m%d]**

**Code:-**

```
import datetime

date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("2022.12.25", '%Y.%m.%d').strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime("2025.12.25", '%Y.%m.%d').strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
today = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y.%m.%d')

if date1 < today:
    print("OVERDUE")
else: 
    print("not overdue")
    
if date2 < today:
    print("OVERDUE")
else:
    print("not overdue")
```

**Output:**

```
OVERDUE
not overdue
```

Reason you should do like this.. when you are comparing in `date,month,year` format it is not guarantees that date will be greater always if the year is greater. example `25.12.2022` `06.01.2023` when you comparing date `25` will be greater than `06` hence the output it gives `25.12.2022`>`06.01.2023` **which is not correct.!** that's why you should compare in `year` than `month` than `date` format..

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. The below comparison is between datetime data types and not Strings:

```
from datetime import datetime

date1 = datetime.strptime("25.12.2022", '%d.%m.%Y') <-- removed the extra strptime
date2 = datetime.strptime("25.12.2025", '%d.%m.%Y') <-- removed the extra strptime
today = datetime.today() <-- removed the strptime

print(type(date1))
print(date2)
print(type(today))

if date1 < today:
    print("OVERDUE")
else:
    print("not overdue")

if date2 < today:
    print("OVERDUE")
else:
    print("not overdue")
```

Output:

> <class 'datetime.datetime'>
>
> 2025-12-25 00:00:00
>
> 'datetime.datetime'>
>
> OVERDUE
>
> not overdue